# why default user-agent is jakarta commons-httpclient 3.1

Tags: user-agent

why default user-agent is jakarta commons-httpclient 3.1 if i did not set the user-agent in header list. What is wrong with my question? Please help me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@1355 : Dont Worry!

In org.apache.commons.httpclient.params there is one class called "DefaultHttpParamsFactory.java". In that class the default param is set.

```
 protected HttpParams createParams() {
        HttpClientParams params = new HttpClientParams(null);

        params.setParameter(HttpMethodParams.USER_AGENT, "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1");
.
.
.
.
.
.
}
```

If a particular parameter value has not been set, this value will be drawn here.

I think it may help you..